# Matlab: Add folder and subfolders persistent to path

Tags: matlab, path

I have a `Matlab` directory in my `Code` folder like this:
`~/Code/Matlab/`

I want the whole content of this folder (and its subfolders) added permanently to the Matlab-path. So that, when I add a new file/ folder into this folder or its subfolders it gets added automatically to the path.

I know how to add a folder permanent to the path but when I add subfolders/ files to it, they are getting not added.

Is this possible and if yes how?

Comment: Have you tried: `addpath ( genpath ( pwd ) )`

Comment: @matlabgui this works for adding the current path but won't add files to the path that were added afterwards to the folder

Comment: it does on all versions of Matlab that I have used - can you show a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Solutions from matlabgui and Richard are the right approach, but will only work for files in the folder/subfolders that exist at the time you ran the command. If you add a new subfolder, you'll need to rerun the command to add the new subfolder to the path. Try creating a shortcut containing the command and add to the shortcut toolbar, if it feels repetitive. There's no "add this folder, its subfolder, and all future subfolders" command, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SamRoberts Please edit existing or provide new answer so I can accept it

Comment: @ProgrammingPete done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

```
addpath(genpath('~/Code/Matlab/'));
savepath
```

This will add your folder, and all its subfolders, to the path. However, if you subsequently add a new subfolder, it will not automatically be added to the path, and you'll need to run the commands again.

I'm afraid there is no "add this folder, its subfolder, and all future subfolders" command.

If this starts to feel repetitive, you could consider creating a shortcut with those commands, and adding it to the MATLAB toolstrip.

Comment: You could consider running an initialize.m script every time you start up MATLAB that runs this command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `genpath` for the subfolders, i.e.

```
addpath(genpath('YourFolder'));
savepath
```

Then, all the files in those folders (even newly added ones) will be permanently available.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to add the path with your [`startup` folder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html). I have my `userpath` folder under version control with Git, and I have folders and submodule folders inside of it with functions that I use throughout projects. I include the following line in my `startup` file: `addpath(genpath(userpath))`. This adds all of those functions to my path as soon as MATLAB opens.

Comment: You can also use [`genpath2`](https://github.com/ssordopalacios/matlab-genpath2) to avoid adding the *.git* folders if you have a similar setup to mine.